# Position a shape in Excel based on its center point

Tags: excel

Is it possible to position a shape by its center point?

I'm trying to overlay shapes onto a picture of a map in Excel and adjust the size of the shapes based on the value in a cell.

I have the sizing portion figured out, but every time my shapes size increases it slowly starts to move to the right and bottom due to the positioning of its left and top. I would like it if the positioning of my circles would not moved once the data gets refreshed. I only want the size of the shape to be altered.

Any thoughts?

[image: Small Shape]

[image: Bigger Shape]

Comment: not sure how you're initially positioning these shapes (e.g.via a macro or manually)...? if via a macro, you can get the size of the circle and shift it to the top and left by the radius..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the X/Y (really Left/Top, since {0,0} is upper left) where you want to put it, it is as simple as subtracting off half the size of the shape to get the center to be there.

Here is some simple code which puts the center of a circle at the corner of cell E8.  I assume you have some way of selecting the shape based on your question.

```
Sub PositionByCenter()

    Dim dbl_x As Double
    Dim dbl_y As Double

    'select a cell just to put it somewhere
    dbl_x = Range("E8").Left
    dbl_y = Range("E8").Top

    'grab a reference to a shape
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)

    'position by the center
    shp.Top = dbl_y - shp.Height / 2
    shp.Left = dbl_x - shp.Width / 2

End Sub
```

Here is what you get after running that with a circle selected.

[image: circle is now at desired spot]

Comment: Thank you. This should work. I guess all I really needed was the logic behind centering a shape based on height / 2, width / 2. I should now be able to replicate this for all of my shapes and over lay them on a map.This is an example of my end code:                                                   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    Shapes("MN").Width = Target.Value
    Shapes("MN").Height = Target.Value
    Shapes("MN").Top = Range("E8").Top - Target.Value / 2
    Shapes("MN").Left = Range("E8").Left - Target.Value / 2
End If
End Sub

Comment: Be sure to replace those calls to `Range("E8").Top` and `Range("E8").Left` with whatever destination you actually intend.